# How can I send money from Spain to my Russian bank account?

Tags: spain, russia, money-transfer

I am Spaniard but now I am studying in Russia and due to sanctions I can no longer transfer money between my accounts. Does anyone know how I can send money from Spain to Russia?

Comment: What did your bank(s) say when you asked them?

Comment: note that part of the purpose of the sanctions is to make people like you unable to transfer money to russia so that you'll be forced to leave.

Comment: @Traveller I I simply used a mobile application where I put my bank card information and you could send the money, I didn't have to go to the bank or tell them anything.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the sanctions, the only safe method I have found to work right now is, to physically travel outside of Russia (I use Turkey for these purposes; but unless you are a Muslim or can speak Turkish, I would really suggest using a different country), get the money you need, and travel back.

One other (risky) option I use is, find a person in Russia who wants to send money outside of Russia (usually to the US, in my cases), vet them to make sure they are honest (I haven't rejected anyone yet, so can't offer advice there), and then make an arrangement where you will send that money from your bank account to their recipient, and they will give this money to you in Rubles.  I am a little surprised that I haven't been scammed the entire time I have done this, but as long as I am the one who initiates the transaction, the odds of stumbling upon a scammer seem pretty low.

Again, I am not recommending this second option, since I myself still feel uneasy when I send the money without receiving anything until my money clears their bank; however, knowing that both sides are affected by the sanctions right now, I can attest to not having been scammed even a single time when doing this.

Comment: The second option sounds as if you could get into trouble for money laundering.

Comment: o.O.  Didn't think that it was.  Any source for me to read to see whether what I'm doing is indeed wrong?  In Wikipedia definition of money laundering, an essential component is that the money is illegally gained (or gained as a result of an illegal act, depending on the country) -- which is not the case here.

Comment: For a money transfer service, money laundering legislation requires them to know their customer, to document things, and so on. You do not think of yourself as a money transfer service, but from the viewpoint of your 'customers' you are -- you help them to move money. And you also help them to circumvent sanctions, which is another factor.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but with that definition, any time I send money to anyone abroad this would make me a transmitter -- I am helping Western Union move money from the abroad into Spain.  You might say, Well, you're the one who contacts Western Union for the transfer -- this is also the case in Russia.  You might say, Well, Western Union is a business -- so are these entities in Russia.  You might say, They clear your money before they pay -- this is also the case here.  This whole concept of me being a transmitter is new to me, so I'm finding it hard to reconcile with a legal transfer.

Comment: You might say, Well, Western Union is a registered transmitter -- well, I've never asked them if they were.  Same as I've never asked the business in Russia whether they are a registered transmitter.  So as far as I'm aware, they are being the transmitter, not me; it's their fault if they're not registered.  Again, it's plausible that my logic has a flaw somewhere; but I just don't get it.

Comment: The point here is that you're dealing with another person, who **also** wants to transfer money. Think it through from the viewpoint of that guy. He comes to you, gives you money in one country, and you pay it out in another country. What if that person in Russia actually wants to pay for a sanctions-busting purchase in the US? (Not very likely that a major player would deal in such small amounts, but who knows?)

Comment: I am 100% sure that Western Union is also interested in moving money from one country to another. Because some countries like the US send a lot more than they receive; consequently, the Western Union is always interested in moving money into the US. So that distinction also doesn't seem to apply here.  Moreover, in both cases, for the other business it's a passive "move if I get a chance to" rather than an "I have to move this money as soon as possible".

Comment: Bottom line is, as long as the government doesn't complain about it, I think I'll continue what I've been doing if it's not obvious why it's wrong.  If the government somehow complains about it, then I can offer these arguments and ask for a clarification -- at that point they will *have to* take their time to come up with a way to distinguish the two cases.  But since I've had no even hints at complaints thus far, as far as I'm aware my arguments are a legitimate justification of what I've been doing.

Comment: I cannot stop you, of course. But if Western Union would offer a service like yours, between Russia and the West, then the OP wouldn't have the problem. Russia is heavily sanctioned.